# Computing adjoint representation on GL(n)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, representation-theory

Suppose I have a complex representation
$$
\pi:G \to GL(4),
$$
(let's say $n=4$) I would like to compute the its composition with the adjoint representation of $GL(4)$ in various cases, for example (1) if $\pi$ is a sum of one dimensional characters, or (2) if $\pi$ is an induced representation, or if (3) $\pi$ is a direct sum of induced representations.

How does Ad$(\pi)$ decompose? I think this should be a matter of combinatorics/linear algebra, but I have not been able to find references or examples to learn how to do this.

Comment: I don't have it handy here to give a precise reference, but I recall this being covered at least partially in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics vol. 2.

Comment: Thanks. Stanley only calculates the trace and character of Ad, and infers that ad has two irreducible components: the trivial rep and matrices of trace 0.

Comment: I mean the general problem of composing reps of $GL_n$.